# Cómo acceder a un atributo de una instancia teniendo el nombre de la instancia en string

Tags: python, lista, objeto, atributos, instancias

Tengo una lista con los nombres de cada instancia de una misma clase (pero son string, "no son objetos"). Quiero recorrer la lista con un `for` y modificar los atributos de cada instancia con ello, pero me salta el error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fixedColor'`.

¿Debería crear otra lista cuyos elementos son objetos como tal, y recorrer esa lista, o hay alguna forma de acceder al atributo del objeto en forma de string?

Quiero aplicarlo en este caso:

```py
listaCartas_temp = listaCartas
listaColores_temp = listaColores

for i in listaCartas:

    a=random.choice(listaCartas_temp)
    listaCartas_temp.remove(a)
    b=random.choice(listaCartas_temp)
    listaCartas_temp.remove(b)
    color = random.choice(listaColores_temp)
    listaColores_temp.remove(color)

    pares.append(tuple([a, b]))

    i.fixedColor = color
```

Tengo varias cartas (son instancias de la clase Carta) y tengo que ordenarlos en pares. Cada par tiene un color asignado (en un atributo). Los pares deben ser totalmente únicos y cada par debe tener un color diferente. Por esa razón elimino la carta en cada iteración de la lista temporal.

Answer (score 1):

En Python puedes ver un objeto como un diccionario, donde los atributos son las llaves. Puedes manipular esos atributos usando notación de diccionarios:

```
objeto["nombre_del_atributo"] = valor_asignado
```

Para que esto funcione debes implementar dos métodos *mágicos*:

- **setattr**(llave, valor). Recibe el nombre del atributo (en string) y el valor para ese atributo. Debe almacenar el atributo.
- **getattr**(llave). Recibe el nombre del atributo (en string) y devuelve el valor asociado.

#### Demo

La clase `Persona` tiene tres atributos: nombre, edad y sexo. Notemos que en los métodos mágicos sólo consideramos los atributos nombre y edad; puedes completar el manejo del sexo.

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre = None
        self.edad = None
        self.sexo = None

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item == "nombre":
            return self.nombre
        elif item == "edad":
            return self.edad
        else:
            return None

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key == "nombre":
            self.nombre = value
        elif key == "edad":
            self.edad = value

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.nombre}, {self.edad} años, {self.sexo}"
```

probemos con

```
persona1 = Persona()
persona1["nombre"] = "Juan"
persona1["edad"] = 20
persona1["sexo"] = "Indefinido"
print(persona1)
```

produce:

```
Juan, 20 años, None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Por supuesto, puedes usar una variable tipo string para acceder al atributo:

```
atributo = "nombre"
persona1[atributo] = "Jorge"

print(persona1[atributo])
```

produce:

```
Jorge

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: claro, pero en vez de tener `persona1` tuviera `"persona1"`, (o sea, el "nombre" del objeto pero del tipo string) ¿podría acceder al atributo de la misma forma? Es decir, `"persona1".nombre`.

Eso es a lo que quiero llegar